# How to use os.fork with sqlalchemy core and flask using API?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have created a user and wish to send email to the user's mail id with details:

```
def send_new_user_mail(new_user_id, plain_passwd):
    '''
    Send mail to new user added
    '''
    s1 = select([users]).where(users.c.id == new_user_id)
    rs1 = conn.execute(s1).fetchone()
    if rs1:
        msg = Message("You are registered to use DMS",
                      sender=app.config['DEFAULT_MAIL_SENDER'],
                      recipients=[rs1[users.c.email]])
        print g.referer, 'g.referer'
        user_details = ('username: ' +  rs1[users.c.email] + '<br>' +
                        'password:' + plain_passwd)
        # TODO: send change password link
        chg_passwd = ('<br><br>You can change password by visiting: ' +
                      '<a href=url_for("change_password")>' +
                      url_for("change_my_password", user_id=rs1[users.c.id]) +
                      '</a>')
        chg_passwd = ''
        msg.html = ('url: ' + '<a href=' + str(g.referer) + '>' +
                    g.referer + '</a></br><br>' + user_details +
                    chg_passwd)
        print msg.html, 'msg.html'
        try:
            with app.app_context():
                mail.send(msg)
                return True
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            return False
    conn1.close()
    return

@app.route('/sf/api/v1.0/users', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    '''
    Add a user 
    '''
    if 'id' in session:
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        trans = conn.begin()
        try:
            if 'first_name' in data:
                data['first_name'] = data['first_name'].title()
            if 'last_name' in data:
                data['last_name'] = data['last_name'].title()
            ins = users.insert().values(data)
            rs = conn.execute(ins)
            mnew_user = rs.inserted_primary_key[0]
            mfolder = create_ftp_user_source_folder(mnew_user)
            trans.commit()
            for g in mgroups:
                ins2 = users_groups.insert().values(
                    user=mnew_user,
                    group=g)
                rs2 = conn1.execute(ins2)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            trans.rollback()
            return jsonify({'message': "Invalid / duplicate details"}), 400
        # user FTP source folder exists
        if mfolder:
            # new_child_proc = 0
            new_child_proc = os.fork()
            print new_child_proc, 'new_child_proc'
            if new_child_proc == 0:
                x = send_new_user_mail(mnew_user, plain_passwd)
                os._exit(0)
            else:
               print 'child:', new_child_proc
            return jsonify({'id': mnew_user}), 201
        else:
            return jsonify(
                {'message': "Cannot create FTP source/already exists"}), 403

    return jsonify({'message': "UNAUTHORIZED"}), 401
```

I tried this code, but get error: 
Other parts of the code also added. If user belongs to a group(s) already, it is not added un users_groups but continues. When a new user is added a source folder is also created in the file system.
As suggested, I forked after storing the value in a variable and triedbut still get same error. Is there any better solution for this?

> (psycopg2.DatabaseError) SSL error: decryption failed or bad record
>   mac

Some error with with connection pooling which I don't understand how to use it here. Please guide. Flask v. 0.11, python 2.7, sqlalchemy core 1.0.8

Comment: In general, if you're getting errors like these when using `fork()`, it means the child process has inherited the parent process's connections *and is trying to use them*. `rs.inserted_primary_key[0]` seems like the most obvious culprit; try copying that into a variable before you fork.

Comment: @univerio I tried and modified as above, but still get the error., pl. suggest

Comment: What does `send_new_user_mail` do then?

Comment: You're making a query in the forked process. Do not do that.

Comment: @univerio. Thx a lot. It worked after removing query from the forked process

Comment: Actually credit goes to @univerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my answer as suggested by @inverio, by removing query part after fork:

```
def send_new_user_mail(memail_id, plain_passwd, mnew_user):    
    '''
    Send mail to new user added to dms with url
    '''
    msg = Message("You are registered to use DMS",
                  sender=app.config['DEFAULT_MAIL_SENDER'],
                  recipients=[memail_id])
    user_details = ('username: ' + memail_id + '<br>' +
                    'password:' + plain_passwd)
    chg_passwd = ''
    msg.html = ('url: ' + '<a href=' + str(g.referer) + '>' +
                g.referer + '</a></br><br>' + user_details +
                chg_passwd)
    try:
        with app.app_context():
            mail.send(msg)
            return True
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return False
    conn1.close()
    return

@app.route('/sf/api/v1.0/users', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    '''
    Add a user and select his group(s)
    '''
    if 'id' in session:
        if session['email'].split("@")[0] == 'ytms.admin' and \
                session['flag'] is True:
            mgroups = []
            mnew_user = None
            mfolder = None
            memail = None
            data = request.get_json(force=True)
            if data['password']:
               # pass
               plain_passwd = data['password']
               mypass = pwd_context.encrypt(data['password'])
               data['password'] = mypass
            if "groups" not in data:
                return jsonify({'message': "Cannot add without group(s)"}), 400
            for g in data["groups"]:
                mgroups.append(g)
            del data["groups"]
            print data, 'data'
            trans = conn.begin()
            try:
                if 'first_name' in data:
                    data['first_name'] = data['first_name'].title()
                if 'last_name' in data:
                    data['last_name'] = data['last_name'].title()
                ins = users.insert().values(data)
                rs = conn.execute(ins)
                mnew_user = rs.inserted_primary_key[0]
                mfolder = create_ftp_user_source_folder(mnew_user)
                memail = data['email']
                trans.commit()
                for g in mgroups:
                    ins2 = users_groups.insert().values(
                        user=mnew_user,
                        group=g)
                    rs2 = conn1.execute(ins2)
            except Exception, e:
                print e
                trans.rollback()
                return jsonify({'message': "Invalid / duplicate details"}), 400
            # user FTP source folder exists
            if mfolder:
                new_child_proc = os.fork()
                if new_child_proc == 0:
                    x = send_new_user_mail(memail, plain_passwd, mnew_user)
                    os._exit(0)
                else:
                   print 'child:', new_child_proc
                return jsonify({'id': mnew_user}), 201
            else:
                return jsonify(
                    {'message': "Cannot create FTP source/already exists"}), 403

    return jsonify({'message': "UNAUTHORIZED"}), 401
```